# Setting body padding with javascript to move below fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have done a lot f searching but can't find anything that works. I am working on a WP theme with a Bootstrap fixed navbar at the top. Everything was going great but as I started adding more menu items, the menu height expands and starts covering the content. Since this is a theme and someone else could start putting a lot of links in the navigation, I need a way to set the body padding to the height of the navbar.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body class="page-template page-template-page-full-width page-template-page-full-width-php page page-id-42">

    <header role="banner">

        <div id="inner-header" class="clearfix">

            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container-fluid nav-container">
                        <nav role="navigation">
                           <div class="span3">
                            <a class="brand" id="logo" title="Just another WordPress site" href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi">
                                                                        <img src="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cc_logo_white.png" alt="Just another WordPress site">
                                                                            <!--<img src="" alt="">-->
                                    </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <div class="span9">
                            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="nav-collapse">
                                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav"><li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/recent-news/">Recent News</a></li><li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-42 current_page_item active"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/test-page/">Full Width Page w/fi</a></li><li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/full-width-page-wo-fi/">Full Width Page w/o FI</a></li><li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/sample-page/">Left Side Bar Page w/FI</a></li><li id="menu-item-118" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/left-sidebar-wo-fi/">Left sidebar w/o FI</a></li><li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/regular-page/">Regular Page w/ FI</a></li><li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://corpuschristi2:8888/corpuschristi/regular-page-wo-fi/">Regular Page w/o FI</a></li></ul>                              </div>
                                                        </div>
                        </nav>


                    </div> <!-- end .nav-container -->
                </div> <!-- end .navbar-inner -->
            </div> <!-- end .navbar -->

        </div> <!-- end #inner-header -->

    </header> <!-- end header -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div style="position: relative">
    <h1 class="title-over-image">Full Width Page w/fi</h1>...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
$('body').css('padding-top',$('.navbar').outerHeight(true));
```

It seems that just using .height has issues getting the value when the height is set to auto. With .outerHeight() it was able to get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

could you just grab the height of the navbar and set the padding using jquery?

```
$('body').css('padding-top',$('.navbar').height)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will say that my JS is a bit lacking. Where would be the best place to add the script? Do I need to put it in a function.

Comment: I believe it just needs to be anywhere in your  `$(document).ready(function(){
    \\put it here
})`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. This seems like it should be a simple thing but I fear there is something interfering with it. Do I need to look out for anything in the CSS styling that could conflict or override this?

Comment: no, javascript should be able to override the CSS. what do you get when you run `console.log($('.navbar').height)` ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at <anonymous>:1:13

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding using jquery.

add below function in function.php

```
<?php
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    jQuery('body').css('padding-top',jQuery('.navbar').height);
} );
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
?>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it didn't work. I do have the wp_footer being automatically loaded at the end of the document so I also tried putting the script in the head but still nothing.

Comment: Is there anything within the CSS styling I should be looking out for that could be overwriting it?

Comment: okay, you can use responsive media query css as per the resolution size

Comment: In this case the resizing of the navigation area isn't related to the window size. I already have it collapsing for smaller screens. The issue is the amount of content, in this case, number of links. I will pass this on and if the person adding links adds enough for the menu to go onto a second line, the nav area expands and content gets covered up.

Comment: add java script in footer.php : <script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
 jQuery('body').css('padding-top',jQuery('.navbar').height);
});   
</script>

Comment: On later versions of jquery `.height` doesn't work - needs to  be `.height()` to get a px value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery('body').css('padding-top',jQuery('.navbar').height());
} );
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
?>
```